# GroupBy on strings (hashcode collision)

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of strings (approx 2000), and I'd like to use **IEnumerable.GroupBy** to group the equal ones.

The problem is though that there are many hash collisions such as *"mysteriously"* and *"well"*. This is probably due to the fact that GroupBy uses **GetHashCode()**, which returns an int, which is too small (or the GetHashCode function for the class String hasn't been implemented nicely).

I guess you could try implementing an overridden **GetHashCode** function or define a custom **IEqualityComparer** and use a different hashcode, but isn't there any way to compare them directly or differently? I know it'll take much longer, but at a small amount it's acceptable. How could I fix this?

Comment: GetHashCode works *with* Equals. It is merely to help in *implementing* a hash-based Map and can show *non-equality* but it cannot prove equality. The standard String.GetHashCode should work sufficiently well for this purpose (please provide a link to support "hasn't been implemented nicely"): an integer can represent a good bit more than 2000 values and occasional collisions just don't matter. You can't subclass String, but you could use an IEqualityComparer .. although I don't know why.

Comment: Also, the assertion about "mysteriously".GetHashCode() == "well".GetHashCode() is wrong in .NET 4.5 - I don't know about other versions but I would be very surprised if any .NET had a String hash code generation that was "absolutely abysmal" as hinted. (However, do keep in mind that hash algorithms *can* be targeted for collision attacks: this is much different than random input resulting in the same hash code. These attacks, and indeed "duplicate hashes" in general, can affect performance but do not affect correctness.)

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I printed all strings out in each group, what I didn't consinder though is that strings can contain multiple lines and thus it looked like it was a match, bad debugging I guess sorry for that!

Comment: Glad the problem is solved :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupBy on strings will only group equal strings together, regardless of whether they have the  same hash code. Since GroupBy uses a hash table under the hood, lots of different strings with the same hash code may degrade performance slightly, but will still give the correct answer.

To prove this to yourself, note that GroupBy works great even with a custom IEqualityComparer that has a terrible hashing function:

```
void Main()
{
    var groups = new[] { "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c" }.GroupBy(s => s, new BadComparer())
        .Select(g => string.Join(",", g))
        .ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, groups));
    // this prints:
    // a,a
    // b,b
    // c,c      
}

public class BadComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> {
    public bool Equals(string a, string b) { return a == b; }
    public int GetHashCode(string s) { return 0; }
}
```

Note also that it's important to group by the string itself rather than by its hash code:

`myStrings.GroupBy(s => s) // works`

`myStrings.GroupBy(s => s.GetHashCode()) // doesn't work`

Comment: Hm this is weird, I have a proof here where GroupBy is giving me an invalid group, though if I test the words in a single array they won't match, hold on